Why does MySQL print "\\." instead of "\." on the command line?
I just want to select backslash-period "(\.)".
In the MySQL client when I run
mysql> select '\\.';
+----+
| \. |
+----+

That is the outcome I want, but when I create a file name reverse.sql contains the same query as following
cat reverse.sql
select '\\';

When I run this query in the following way I get:
mysql -h mysqlhost -u admin -p -N mydatabase < reverse.sql

\\.

Instead of \. I get \\..
Because backslash-period is special character bash hinders me I guess, but is there any way to solve this issue and get "\." instead of "\\."?
MySQL version 8.0.37
Thanks!

Your reverse.sql doesn't select the period, is that just a typo?

Use the --raw option to prevent escaping output.

% mysql -N < reverse.sql      
\\.

% mysql --raw -N < reverse.sql
\.

Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_raw

For nontabular output (such as is produced in batch mode or when the --batch or --silent option is given), special characters are escaped in the output so they can be identified easily. Newline, tab, NUL, and backslash are written as \n, \t, \0, and \\. The --raw option disables this character escaping.

